# menuOptions how to change color?

Tags: java, android

When I click item in the first picture I get something that you can see in the second picture. And as you can see I get white item. Does anyone know how to change its color?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkoNV.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHQKO.jpg

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item
         android:id="@+id/tools"
         android:title="123123" >

       <group
          android:checkableBehavior="all">
         <menu >
           <item
             android:id="@+id/action_sort_az"
             android:title="@string/sort_az"
             android:checked="true"
             app:showAsAction="never"
             app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox" />

             ....

           <item android:id="@+id/action_sort_id_asc"
             android:title="@string/snachala_novye"
             app:actionViewClass="android.widget.CheckBox" />

        </menu>
     </group>

     </item>
</menu>
```

style.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#E9E2BF</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#E9E2BF</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#E9E2BF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="customTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:itemBackground">#424242</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#E9E2BF</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1b1b1b</item>
        <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/MyTextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/mycolor</item>
    </style>

    ...

</resources>
```

Comment: Can you also post the content of the `styles.xml` just to double check the theming you used?

Comment: @denis_lor https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NShlS2suGrMU4-Vg5rpGGB3RhYCWIxBILUB-yGDSdcY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you post the content as well of how are you using the menu item xml file that you posted in the question? Is it used through a Toolbar, NavigationView, ActionBar...? Just post the xml layout that is referencing the menu xml posted in your question.

Comment: @denis_lor 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jdYLJ7Wx-cIC3TrYu9LOS6lc6TU1LIOqK1Cnu2fYbVI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Great! I updated your question with the file you sent as links to give everyone more clarity on your code and as well I gave you an answer on my thoughts about it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have already modified the background colors of your menu items, which I also achieved by adding to my Style 
`<item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/myColors</item>` and then you have the issue with the Header of the SubMenu which is White or being really precise is `<color name="material_grey_50">#fffafafa</color>` applied automatically by the parent theme you are using Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar.

To change the color of the header title of the submenu you will need your style.xml to have **actionBarPopupTheme** attribute and have the custom **MyStyle** style that I have written as below:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/popup</item>
        <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/MyStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

[image: Check screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. Did I do it correctly?
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SfmKlyS2vLyrh9pJ5s275XeEHcGVtyKHlydMVKBQj-Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The 3 dots that I put are not really meant to be in the style.xml file is just to say that there can be other styles there but the important part that interest your question is the part I wrote. Please can you maybe write or update your question by adding further stuff instead of posting it as a google docs? Is not a good practice to hide stuff in links and is better to make it more visible to all other stackoverflow members so they can contribute as well

Comment: i removed these dots and unfortunately it changed nothing, it still doen't work :(

Comment: My application theme is customTheme and android:itemBackground is already defined.

Comment: Your screenshot looks ok. Have tried to click "123123"? 
I even applied selector - all items changed color and change color when I click them except "123123". It always has white background. Probably because it is not item it is kind of title.

Comment: @СашаСерегин Now I see your point. I just re-edited my answer in order to let you know the solution that I have found! Let me know if it is the correct answer for you and mark it in case as correct in case it is

Answer (score 0):

Add a custom style to your `style.xml` file with parent `parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"` and give it a `popupBackground` attribute